# Turn off Paypal shipping and tax?

Tags: paypal

I have added a web page to accept Paypal to an existing site which sells books. When the seller checks out, the shipping and tax are added. The problem is, now they want to additionally charge a fee for a conference registration and have no shipping or tax applied. How do I change the Paypal html coding on the page with buttons specifically set up for this registration charge to be added to their Paypal cart?

Comment: This topic (or related topic) on [Paypal site](https://www.paypal.com/ie/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_pdn_cart_overrides_outside).